# Problema para remover uma tag img dentro do array pelo id da imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagem

estou fazendo uma preview de imagens com remoção da imagem. No caso eu preciso remover o elemento selecionado de dentro do array usando o id da tag img. Eu já consigo levar o id até a função que irá remover, porém, não consigo acessar o elemento de imagem pelo id do mesmo que está dentro do array.

Eis aqui o código para análise:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
          if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
          }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            base64imgs.push("<img class='thumb' id='img_"+id+"' src='"+e.target.result+"' >");
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    } 

$('#output_box_foto').append("<img class='thumb' id='img_"+id+"' src='"+URL.createObjectURL(files_show[i])+"' onclick='Remover("+id+")'>");

function Remover(id) {
    id_img_remove="#img_"+id;
    $(id_img_remove).remove(); 
    //Acima eu apenas removo visualmente a imagem, e abaixo seria o trecho de código que não sei como fazer para remover o elemento de dentro do meu array. Aqui no caso eu gostaria de remover o elemento IMG pelo Id dele de dentro do array
    base64imgs // Já tentei slice, preg...sem êxito
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

O array base64 contém strings e não objetos, então acredito que você precise buscar por texto e não seletor.

Seria algo assim:

```
var meuarray = [
        '<img id="img1" src="img1.jpg" />',
        '<img id="img2" src="img2.jpg" />',
        '<img id="img3" src="img3.jpg" />'
    ];

    var index = -1;

    $(meuarray).each(function (i, item) {

        if (item.indexOf('id="img1"') > -1)
        {
            index = i;
        }
    });

    if (index > -1) {
        meuarray.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log(meuarray);
```

---

Adicionalmente...

Caso você queira trabalhar com seletores do jQuery, sugiro que crie seus objetos com jQuery ao invés de append com texto.
Por exemplo esse bloco:

> `$('#output_box_foto').append("<img class='thumb' id='img_"+id+"'src='"+URL.createObjectURL(files_show[i])+"' onclick='Remover("+id+")'>");`

Ficaria assim:

```
var imgBoxFoto = $('<img>', {
    class: "thumb", 
    id: "meuid", 
    src:"minhaurl"
}).on("click", function(el){
    Remover(id);
});

$('#output_box_foto').append(imgBoxFoto);
```

Note que você também pode substituir o atributo onclick do html e registrar direto no objeto, sem que seu "id" e o nome do método fiquem expostos no html.

Transformando o seu array de texto (das tags img) em objetos ficariam assim:

```
    //array de objetos jQuery
    var meuarray2 = [
        $('<img>', { id: 'img1', src: 'img1.jpg' }),
        $('<img>', { id: 'img2', src: 'img2.jpg' }),
        $('<img>', { id: 'img3', src: 'img3.jpg' })
    ];

    //Os objetos criados em memória no jQuery ficam com formato de function "n.fn.init[1]"
    //Precisa transformá-los em objetos referenciáveis com o array:
    meuarray2 = $(meuarray2).map(function () { return this.toArray(); });

    //usa o filter passando o id -- Também poderia ser qualquer seletor (classe, data, type, etc)
    var index = meuarray2.index($(meuarray2).filter('#img1'));

    //faz o splice para eliminar o valor:
    if (index > -1) {
        meuarray2.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log(meuarray2);
```

Comment: Olá Ericson, eu entendi perfeitamente o que você quis dizer, realmente é uma forma muito melhor e mais organizada, porém, só me surgiu uma dificuldade, acho que talvez seja problema com o DOM, quando eu clico nas imagens para verificar o ID delas, ele pega sempre o último id. Coloquei exatamente da forma que você me mandou 

var imgBoxFoto = $('<img>', {
    class: "thumb", 
    id: "meuid", 
    src:"minhaurl"
}).on("click", function(el){
    Remover(id);
});

Comment: No caso o evento Remover(id) , o parâmetro id sempre é o mesmo?


Você pode usar atributos datas para armazenar valores nos elemento
Ficaria assim:
 $('<img>', { class: "thumb", id: "meuid", src:"minhaurl" }).data('id', 'meuid').on("click", function(el){ Remover($(el.currentTarget).data('id')); });

Comment: Nossa você é realmente incrível. Funcionou perfeitamente, não conhecia esse atributo data. Muito Obrigado Ericson!

Comment: Você ainda poderia pegar o id do emento assim, sem usar data:

function(el){ 
   Remover($(el.currentTarget).attr('id'));
}

Comment: Ericson, só mais uma pergunta quando eu crio o array, como eu faço pra pegar um valor do objeto, no caso eu to tentando fazer assim

seletor = $('<img>', {
           class: "thumb", 
           id: "img_"+contador_img, 
           src: e.target.result
       });
       base64imgs.push(seletor);

Como eu faço depois para pegar o src, por exemplo?

Comment: Se vc já tem o objeto, é só usar attr do jQuery: 
meuObjeto.attr('src');

Se você for procurar o objeto dentro do array:
$(meuarray2).filter('#img1').attr('src')

Caso o filter retorne mais de um valor, você precisa percorrer o array:
$(meuarray2).filter('#img1')[0].attr('src')

Comment: Tentei, mas não consegui, tanto para pegar o valor quanto para remover, usei o seu exemplo e no alert aparece Object object

base64imgs = $(base64imgs).map(function () { return this.toArray(); });

 var index = base64imgs.index($(base64imgs).filter(id));


    if (index > -1) {
        base64imgs.splice(index, 1);
    }

    alert(base64imgs); // retorna Object object

// Inseri dessa maneira
seletor = $('<img>', {
           class: "thumb", 
           id: "img_"+contador_img, 
           src: e.target.result
       });
       base64imgs.push(seletor);

Comment: a variável base64imgs é um array, por isso no alert apresenta Object object. Para pegar o valor o src de um id especifico, poderia ser assim:
$(meuarray2).filter('#img1').attr('src');    
Se quiser de todos, precisa de um for: $(meuarray).each(function(i, item){ alert($(item).attr('src')) })

Comment: tentei novamente, joguei um id que sei que existe, porém apareceu undefined

Comment: Não estou conseguindo Ericson

Comment: Consegui, me desculpe, foi erro meu.

Comment: @FábioMonteiro Não esqueça de, além de aceitar a melhor resposta, também dar um *upvote* na resposta do colega que te ajudou! Isso contribui não somente com quem te ajudou mas também com as outras pessoas que podem estar buscando referências que tenham boa reputação dentro da comunidade. ;)

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Aqui diz que preciso ter 15 de reputação, não consigo dar upvote ainda =(